# Showing the text and link for the next menu item using JS, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a navigation link that goes to the next item in my menu. I want the link to display the text for the next item in the menu and when clicked, it should go to that item.
The behavior that i am trying to copy is on this page https://www.youvisit.com/tour/sfsu/88825?tourid=tour1

That right navigation link.

I have tried the following JS function.

```
     // Function to update the next menu item text and link
    function updateNextMenuItem() {
      var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
      var nextMenuItemIndex = -1;

      // Find the index of the next menu item
      for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].classList.contains('active')) {
          nextMenuItemIndex = i + 1;
          break;
        }
      }

      var nextMenuItemElement = document.getElementById('nextMenuItem');

      // Clear the existing content
      nextMenuItemElement.innerHTML = '';

      // If there is a next menu item, populate the content
      if (nextMenuItemIndex !== -1 && nextMenuItemIndex < menuItems.length) {
        var nextMenuItem = menuItems[nextMenuItemIndex];
        var nextMenuItemText = nextMenuItem.textContent;
        var nextMenuItemLink = '#' + nextMenuItemText.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');

        // Create the link element
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        linkElement.href = nextMenuItemLink;
        linkElement.textContent = nextMenuItemText;

        // Append the link to the nextMenuItem element
        nextMenuItemElement.appendChild(linkElement);
      } else {
        nextMenuItemElement.innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    // Add event listener to menu items
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
      menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        updateNextMenuItem();
      });
    }

    // Call the updateNextMenuItem function initially
    updateNextMenuItem();
```

Unfortunately, this is not working and I do not know where exactly I am going wrong.

This is the complete snippet for the page, in case that helps:

EDIT: Updated my script to the latest one I have
EDIT2:  I was asked to add this as a code snippet, hopefully i did it correctly. Here goes

```js
   function changeBackground(imageUrl) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imageUrl + "')";
      updateNextMenuItem();
    }

    function toggleMenu() {
      var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
      menu.classList.toggle('show');
    }

    // Add event listener to show/hide the menu on hover
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    var isHoveringMenu = false;

    // Show menu on hover
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
      if (event.clientX <= 10) {
        menu.classList.add('show');
        isHoveringMenu = true;
      } else if (!isHoveringMenu) {
        menu.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });

    // Add event listener to hide the menu when clicking outside
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var isClickInsideMenu = menu.contains(event.target);
      if (!isClickInsideMenu && !isHoveringMenu) {
        menu.classList.remove('show');
      }
    });

    // Function to update the next menu item text and link
    function updateNextMenuItem() {
      var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
      var nextMenuItemIndex = -1;

      // Find the index of the next menu item
      for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].classList.contains('active')) {
          nextMenuItemIndex = i + 1;
          break;
        }
      }

      var nextMenuItemElement = document.getElementById('nextMenuItem');

      // Clear the existing content
      nextMenuItemElement.innerHTML = '';

      // If there is a next menu item, populate the content
      if (nextMenuItemIndex !== -1 && nextMenuItemIndex < menuItems.length) {
        var nextMenuItem = menuItems[nextMenuItemIndex];
        var nextMenuItemText = nextMenuItem.textContent;
        var nextMenuItemLink = '#' + nextMenuItemText.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');

        // Create the link element
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        linkElement.href = nextMenuItemLink;
        linkElement.textContent = nextMenuItemText;

        // Append the link to the nextMenuItem element
        nextMenuItemElement.appendChild(linkElement);
      } else {
        nextMenuItemElement.innerHTML = '';
      }
    }

    // Add event listener to menu items
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
      menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        updateNextMenuItem();
      });
    }

    // Call the updateNextMenuItem function initially
    updateNextMenuItem();
```

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      transition: margin-left 0.3s;
      font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
      display: flex;
    }

    #menu {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100vh;
      background: #f2f2f2;
      overflow-y: auto;
      transition: width 0.3s;
      margin-left: -250px;
      color: #b4b4b4;
    }

    #menu.show {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    #menu ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #menu li {
      padding: 10px;
      height: 100px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    #menu li::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

    #menu li:hover::before,
    #menu li.active::before {
      opacity: 0;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #menu li:not(:hover):not(.active)::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    #menu li span {
      display: block;
    }

    #menu li:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 5px;
    }

    #menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #333;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #nextMenuItem {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      right: 10px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CCSF</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('1.jpg');" style="background-image: url('1.jpg');">Welcome to CCSF!</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('2.jpg');" style="background-image: url('2.jpg');">Multi-Use Building (MUB)</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('3.jpg');" style="background-image: url('3.jpg');">Smith Hall, Ram Plaza, and Student Union</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('4.jpg');">Louise and Claude Rosenberg, Jr. Library and Learning Resource Center</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('1.jpg');">George M. Rush Stadium</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('2.jpg');">Batmale Hall</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('3.jpg');">Visual Arts</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('4.jpg');">Create Arts</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('1.jpg');">Arts Extension</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('2.jpg');">Student Health Center</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('3.jpg');">Science Hall and Cloud Hall</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('4.jpg');">Future Buildings</li>
      <li onclick="changeBackground('1.jpg');">Thank You for Visiting CCSF!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="nextMenuItem"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you calling `updateNextMenuItem()` when the menu item is clicked? Looks like you just call it once for setting up the button initially but does not seem to attach it to an event listener to handle clicks

Comment: Can you add the example as stack snippet. And I think you're missing closeing tag for `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of duplicate work being done including overwriting your own classes. Here is how you could clean up your code.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'1.jpg');" style="background-image: url('1.jpg');">Welcome to CCSF!</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'2.jpg');" style="background-image: url('2.jpg');">Multi-Use Building (MUB)</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'3.jpg');" style="background-image: url('3.jpg');">Smith Hall, Ram Plaza, and Student Union</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'4.jpg');">Louise and Claude Rosenberg, Jr. Library and Learning Resource Center</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'1.jpg');">George M. Rush Stadium</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'2.jpg');">Batmale Hall</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'3.jpg');">Visual Arts</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'4.jpg');">Create Arts</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'1.jpg');">Arts Extension</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'2.jpg');">Student Health Center</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'3.jpg');">Science Hall and Cloud Hall</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'4.jpg');">Future Buildings</li>
    <li onclick="changeBackground(this,'1.jpg');">Thank You for Visiting CCSF!</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="nextMenuItem"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
/* Added to Style */
#nextMenuItem {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
const menuItems = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');
const nextMenuItemElement = document.getElementById('nextMenuItem');
let activeMenuItem = null;

function changeBackground(button, imageUrl) {
  if (activeMenuItem) activeMenuItem.classList.remove('active');
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imageUrl + "')";
  button.classList.add('active');
  activeMenuItem = button;
  updateNextMenuItem();
}

function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  menu.classList.toggle('show');
}

// Show menu on hover
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (event.clientX > 30) return null;
  menu.classList.add('show');
});

// Add event listener to hide the menu when clicking outside
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const isClickInsideMenu = menu.contains(event.target);
  // const isClickInsideNext = nextMenuItemElement.contains(event.target);
  // const isOrphaned = event.target.parentElement == null;

  if (isClickInsideMenu) return null;
  // if (isClickInsideMenu || isClickInsideNext || isOrphaned) return null;

  menu.classList.remove('show');
});

// Function to update the next menu item text and link
function updateNextMenuItem() {
  // Clear the existing content
  nextMenuItemElement.innerHTML = '';

  if (!activeMenuItem.nextElementSibling) return null;

  const nextMenuItem = activeMenuItem.nextElementSibling;
  const nextMenuItemText = nextMenuItem.textContent;
  const nextMenuItemLink = '#' + nextMenuItemText.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');

  // Click on the next menu item
  const linkElement = document.createElement('div');
  linkElement.textContent = nextMenuItemText;
  linkElement.onclick = () => nextMenuItem.click();

  nextMenuItemElement.appendChild(linkElement);
}
```

Comment: Hi @svarlitskiy , thank you for cleaning up the code. Helps a lot. The text now shows up as well. However, when i click that link from the right side link, the background does not change, It remains the same as the previous link which is not the expected behavior. Each menu section has its own background.

Comment: I reworked `updateNextMenuItem` so that the method creates a div with a click on the `nextMenuItem`, that will handle all the background changes. I also added a cursor pointer css to nextMenuItem element because it is no longer a link. Next, if you want the menu to remain open when you click on nextMenuItem element, then uncomment the code in the document click eventListener. If not, then you can delete those lines.